# Programmatically add view one below other in relative layout

Tags: android

I want something like this programmatically:

```
view1 |  view2
view3 |  view4
----------------
view1 |  view2
view3 |  view4
----------------
view1 |  view2
view3 |  view4
---------------
...........
......
which keeps repeating
--------------
```

I don't want to use ListView.

Comment: You can use Inflated Views and add them via loop..!!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Important: Remember to set the ID for each view.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setId(1);
tv1.setText("textView1");

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());
tv2.setId(2);
tv2.setText("textView2");

TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());
tv3.setId(3);
tv3.setText("textView3");

TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
params4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv3.getId());
params4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tv3.getId());
tv4.setId(4);
tv4.setText("textView4");

layout.addView(tv1, params1);
layout.addView(tv2, params2);
layout.addView(tv3, params3);
layout.addView(tv4, params4);
```

Comment: Remember to start the id for components from 1 and not 0. Like tv1.setId(0) and tv2.setId(1) would get you both the components at the same place. setId(1) and setId(2) would solve it.

Comment: Better to use `tv1.setId(View.generateViewId());` for setting the id.

Comment: View.generateViewId() can only be used in API 17. What can be used in case API is less than 17?

Comment: Use ViewCompat.generateViewId() instead

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using multiple layout params as suggested in @Askilondz answer, you can use `addRule` and `removeRule` as below:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                                                                     
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setId(View.generateViewId());
tv1.setText("textView1");

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setId(View.generateViewId());
tv2.setText("textView2");
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());
rl.addView(tv2, lp);
lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
.
.
.
```

If you are using SDK < 17, you have to create `id's.xml` file, as `values -> ids.xml` with structure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tv1" type="id" />
    <item name="tv2" type="id" />
</resources>
```

and set them in your code as:

```
tv1.setId(R.id.tv1);
tv2.setId(R.id.tv2);
```

**UPDATE**
It looks the Adding multiple rules for the same LayoutParams not working fine, anyhow, I'll keep my answer in case someone fine something usefull in it for him

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);


// set the Drawable on the ImageView
imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

// center the Image
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Hi! For params call method addRule(BELOW, id_of_last_child).