# Insert a TextView under an others in a RelativeLayout in a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I would like to know, how can i add a lot of number of TextView to an RelativeLayout in a ScrollView (for textview can scroll up, of course)

In my XML code, it's easy :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bde" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Except i would like add in Java code, for that each TextView from a DB (no problems with db), add himself in layout and the more important, the one after the other.

Now, i have :

```
 //Layout in ScrollView
 RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_);

 //for add TextView
 for(int i = 0 ; i < nbr_limite ; i++){
TextView v1 = new TextView(r.getContext());

v1.setText("Test n_"+i);
v1.setId(i+1);

r.addView(v1);
 }
```

In fact, i would like a : `android:layout_below="@id/textView1"` but in Java and replace the  : `@id/textView1` by a `getLastId()` roughly said.

And more roughly, it will be something like : `r.addLastView(v1)`

I waiting for your answer or your comment :)

Comment: why not to use a LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv = new TextView(r.getContext());
v1.setText("Test n_"+i);
v1.setId(i+1);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId()-1);


r.addView(tv);
```

also this is an answer for your question .... [Programatically add view one below other in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296959/programatically-add-view-one-below-other-in-relative-layout)