# add a content view to a dialog

Tags: android, listview

I try to add a `Edittext` and a `ListView` to a Dialog.
I use `dialog.addContentView(lstcontent,params)` method to add a view to dialog.

here is my Code:

```
dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new
LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

dialog.addContentView(edittext, lp);
dialog.addContentView(listview,lp);

dialog.show();
```

but my listview is on the edittext. I want to set edittext above of the listview.

[image: here is capture of screen]

I used from this too:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(G.context, (AttributeSet) params);

layout.addView(input);
layout.addView(lstcontent);
dialog.setcontentView(layout);
```

but this crashed application:
    LayoutParams cannout be cast to android.util.Attributeset

Comment: why don't you set your activity's theme as dialog from the xml.Simply start using intent.It will show as dialog.You can set the view too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the new way to this issue.

```
LayoutInflater inflate2 = ((Activity) G.context).getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflate2.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

input = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edt1);
lstcontent = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.lst1);

lstcontent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is `layout_dialog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/lst1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >    
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to use `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)` and use your own layout

Comment: thank you but I have an error while casting paramets

Comment: LayoutParams cannot be cast. See again my question I edited that

Comment: any reason to create the layout in java rather than xml? I think it would be easier if you go the xml way

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative layout like

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and then

```
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id);
```

for more info [Programatically add view one below other in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296959/programatically-add-view-one-below-other-in-relative-layout)

**//EDIT**

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, LISTVIEW_ID);
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, EDITTEXT_INPUT_ID);

layout.addView(EDITTEXTID, params1);
layout.addView(LISTVIEW, params2);
```

and now you have to set this layout for your **DIALOG** and it should work