# android relative layout below not working in programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-relativelayout

I try  to create  relative layout programmatically.I wrote some code and I create layout ,I inflated my layout with my own custom view .I can't to control layout witch I created programmatically
addRulle not working compile.
This is a my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Bisoutflowproducttxt2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/credomoreinfo"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="moreinfo"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:textColor="#363636"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addmore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Bisoutflowproducttxt2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Bisoutflowproducttxt2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/add_icon" />
```

and this is a my java code

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatelayout, null, false);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.addmore);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);

customlayout.addView(view);
```

As I said added new layout but I can not control my new layout.I want to my layout should be bellow my imageview
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically add view one below other in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296959/programmatically-add-view-one-below-other-in-relative-layout)