# How to include layout dynamically down in the view hierarchy?

Tags: android, android-layout

It is not a duplicate question.
I have a xml layout which have alot of things and I'm including 2 layouts which have visibility gone.

```
<include layout="@layout/some_layout" />
```

Now I'm adding imageviews dynamically.

```
layout.addView(imageview);
```

But it is coming top in the hierarchy of layout.
i.e. Whenever I am setting visibility of my include layout as visible. The dynamically added imageviews overlaps it.

How can I add this down in the hierarchy?

Comment: Post your code, or prepare simple example with this behavior.

Comment: which is your parent layout ?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya Relative Layout.

Comment: @ArturSzymański I just have a invisble xml. Now  I am adding some imageviews dynamically. Now when I set the visibility of actual xml as visible. It shows below the imageview. Imageviews is coming above all and overlaps everything. I want this vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically add view one below other in relative layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296959/programatically-add-view-one-below-other-in-relative-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout.addView(view,index);` to add imageview where index is less than the index of included layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add id in your include layout like

```
<include android:id="@+id/include1" layout="@layout/some_layout" />
```

Use `RalativeLayout` rule like

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.include1);
layout.addView(imageview, params1);
```