# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams addRule() not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to position each of my new labels under each other. Each one gets a new ID as they are added to the screen, and provided that the label is not the first one `(idnumer != 0)` , they are positioned below the previous label ( the first one is added to the top). However , they aren't going in right and overlap each other at the top. What am I doing wrong?

```
while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
    TextView mTextv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    mTextv.setText(line);
    RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlX);
    mTextv.setTextSize(20);
    mTextv.setId(idnumber);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsX = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsX.setMargins(15,15,15,5);
    if(idnumber != 0) {                 
        paramsX.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, findViewById(idnumber - 1).getId());
    }
    mTextv.setLayoutParams(paramsX);
    idnumber += 1;
    mTextv.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    mTextv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#009500"));
    linearLayout.addView(mTextv);
    scrollerF.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your description correctly, but the first one cannot have ID `0`. You have to start at at least `1`.

Comment: Okay I'll try that. It did have an id of 0 to begin with

Comment: Also, `findViewById(idnumber - 1).getId()` is kinda unnecessary. It's the same as just `idnumber - 1`.

Comment: Use below link, it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296959/programatically-add-view-one-below-other-in-relative-layout

Comment: Thanks, got the answer !!