# How can I avoid overlapping when addView to RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

There are some Textview,I need to add them in RelativeLayout dynamically. How can I add them without overlap with previous ? thx :D

```
public class CusRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private String TAG = "CusRelativeLayout";
    ...
    public void add(String s){

        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(s);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();

        int[] xy = getRandomXY();

        if(childCount == 0){
            //no view
            params.setMargins(xy[0],xy[1],0,0);

        }else{

          //what shoud I do???

        }

        addView(tv,params);

    }
    ...
}
```

It looks like this：
  [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggCOp.png)

when I add the first tag, I just need to get random X and Y,and new a textview.I use the method setMargins(x,y,0,0) to adding in the RelativeLayout.

But when I add the second tag , I can use getTop(),getLeft(),getHeight(),getiWidth() to getting the previous position and range.And use getRandomXY() to getting random X and Y for the second.But I can't get the range of the second to determine whether the second overlaps with the first

I tried to do this

```
    final TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(s);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    tv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG,"height:" + tv.getHeight());
            Log.e(TAG,"width:" + tv.getWidth());
        }
    });
```

but the value is 0

If I just determine by X and Y , It will be this case.[determine by X and Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN93x.png)

I just want to get the range of the new tag before adding to the RelativeLayout ,so I can determine whether it will overlap with the previous.

if I can determine all the tag position before add in Relativelayout?(I know the exact number of tag)

Comment: What does this look like visually? Couldn't you use a standard LinearLayout instead?

Comment: Please check the question update,thank you

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout is made to allow views to overlap each other. You could use a LinearLayout.
If you for some reason need to stick to RelativeLayout, then you have to place your new View with some layout parameters relative to previously added children

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);
```

instead of R.id.below_id you could use your own ids that you have set on other children
Take a look here
[Programatically add view one below other in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296959/programatically-add-view-one-below-other-in-relative-layout)